# Sort by relation model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=_("Price"), default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
   ...


class Bid(models.Model):
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order, verbose_name=_("Order"), related_name="orders")
   bid = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=_("Bid"), default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
   status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Status"), choices=BID_STATUSES, default=BID_STATES_IN_BIDS)
   ...
```

I need sort Orders by price of Orders and by bid of Bids where status == BID_STATES_IN_BIDS.

How can I get this result?

It should be view like following:

```
Order:
    id: 1
    price: 100
    bids: None
Order:
    id: 2
    price: None
    bids:
        bid:
            id: 1
            bid: 110
            status: 1   #Actual
        bid: 
            id: 2
            bid: 150
            status: 2
Order:
    id: 3
    price: 130
    bids: None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(bid__status=BID_STATES_IN_BIDS).order_by('price')
```

You can find out about reverse lookups here [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
bids = Bid.objects.filter(status=BID_STATES_IN_BIDS).order_by('order__price', 'bid')
```

> To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when you are querying across model relations. That is, the name of the field, followed by a double underscore (__), followed by the name of the field in the new model, and so on for as many models as you want to join.